# typescript function generic parameter in spread argument

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I have the following function:

```js
type SomeType<T> = Record<string, T>;
declare function test<T>(...args: SomeType<T>[]): T;
```

I would like to call it like that (a should be of type `number|string`):

```js
const a = test({a: 3}, {b: "as"});
```

but that way I get an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`
can I make this work without explicitly passing the generic argument `number|string` or using conditional types?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAJQgGM4AnAE3QGdgyBLAOwHMAaKbAKApIBsBDMtABmAV0bFg9OIyjAItTFgAUAOnWDm1AFyxEKNEoDaAXQCUu5AG5OpRrSj88chcGUBvfroDMAX3buAEa6AET81CG%20ZjacAPSxUHYU9FIy-LxyaFDUcLyiqYxxCTzEAkJQYhIFLorIUBAAHvKMFNRQ4gDWjHAA7oymKuqqmjocFhz1TRAtbfBIqJDoTMIQZIRYplAA-IRQuowQAG6rNkA)

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're stuck with writing `const a = test<string|number>({a: 3}, {b: "as"});`, but not sure enough to make it an answer. :-)

Comment: oh yeah sorry, i forgot that in my question i dont want to explicitly add the generic on every call. Why cant typescript not just infer it as a union type. I mean its possible as i suggested using conditional types (as i have shown in the playground, but thats also really messy)

Comment: Don't worry, your question pretty strongly implied you didn't want to do that. :-) It's just I think you're stuck with it. TypeScript only goes so far with inference.

Answer (score 1):

Variadic tuples might help:

```
declare function test<T extends any[]>(...args: [...T]): T;

const a = test({ a: 3 }, { b: "as" });
```

Comment: Just because it works, i wouldn't pass this solution to any production code because `any`, really means `any` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any

Comment: @ArtemVadimovichSolovev That was just to show how it could be accomplished, of course you might write `extends Record<whatever>` suits their need